# How to update an init script

Tags: init-script, init.d

What is the proper way to update an init script an ubuntu system?

I am trying to upgrade my version of gitlab from 6-0 to 6-1, part of the upgrade consists of replacing the init script.

[Upgrade instructions - step 6](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-6.1.md)

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/gitlab
sudo curl --output /etc/init.d/gitlab https://raw.github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/6-1-stable/lib/support/init.d/gitlab
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/gitlab
```

I find that after updating the init script, calling script does nothing. Normally it prints out the processes id of the gitlab service

```
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/gitlab status
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# (notice how nothing happens)

#No gitlab process is running
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# ps aux |grep gitlab
root      4519  0.0  0.1   9384   928 pts/0    R+   20:03   0:00 grep --color=auto gitlab
```

---

**Steps I have taken to troubleshoot this:**

Make sure it is executable

```
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# ll gitlab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7195 Sep 28 19:29 gitlab*
```

Strace the script

```
    root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# strace ./gitlab
execve("./gitlab", ["./gitlab"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xb29000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd33a1a8000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22291, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22291, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd33a1a2000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\30\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1811128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3925208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd339bc9000
mprotect(0x7fd339d7e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd339f7d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7fd339f7d000
mmap(0x7fd339f83000, 17624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd339f83000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd33a1a1000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd33a1a0000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd33a19f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd33a1a0700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd339f7d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x619000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fd33a1aa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd33a1a2000, 22291)           = 0
getpid()                                = 4459
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x40f100, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd339bff4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xb29000
brk(0xb4a000)                           = 0xb4a000
getppid()                               = 4458
stat("/etc/init.d", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("./gitlab", O_RDONLY)              = 3
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x40f100, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd339bff4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd339bff4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd339bff4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
read(10, "#! /bin/sh\n\n# GITLAB\n# Maintaine"..., 8192) = 7195
stat("/usr/local/sbin/sudo", 0x7fffcbf518d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/sudo", 0x7fffcbf518d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/sudo", 0x7fffcbf518d0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=71288, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd33a1a09d0) = 4460
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 4460
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x11)                      = 4460
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

I am more familiar with Cent than Ubuntu, and I hear mixed opinions on manually executing update-rc.d. I've tried it anyway per the [suggestion of this blog](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/system-startstop-links-for-etcinit-dnginx-already-exist/)

```
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# sudo update-rc.d -f gitlab remove
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/gitlab ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20gitlab
   /etc/rc1.d/K20gitlab
   /etc/rc2.d/S20gitlab
   /etc/rc3.d/S20gitlab
   /etc/rc4.d/S20gitlab
   /etc/rc5.d/S20gitlab
   /etc/rc6.d/K20gitlab
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d gitlab defaults
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/gitlab ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc1.d/K20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc6.d/K20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc2.d/S20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc3.d/S20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc4.d/S20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
   /etc/rc5.d/S20gitlab -> ../init.d/gitlab
```

No luck, the script still doesn't run.

Is there anything else that must be done on ubuntu systems to upgrade init scripts?

---

**Update1:**

Looking at /var/log/auth.log shows:

```
vagrant@gitlab:~$ sudo su -
root@gitlab:~# /etc/init.d/gitlab status
root@gitlab:~# tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 28 20:52:31 gitlab su[2205]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 20:52:31 gitlab sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 20:52:34 gitlab sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
Sep 28 20:52:34 gitlab sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by vagrant(uid=1000)
Sep 28 20:52:34 gitlab su[2311]: Successful su for root by root
Sep 28 20:52:34 gitlab su[2311]: + /dev/pts/0 root:root
Sep 28 20:52:34 gitlab su[2311]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by vagrant(uid=0)
Sep 28 20:52:43 gitlab sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=git ; COMMAND=/bin/false -c /etc/init.d/gitlab status
Sep 28 20:52:43 gitlab sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user git by vagrant(uid=0)
Sep 28 20:52:43 gitlab sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user git
```

**Update2**

I've done a diff of the init scripts between 6-0-stable and 6-1-stable. It appears to have been an almost complete rewrite.

The diff is located here:
https://gist.github.com/spudstud/6747146#file-diff-gitlab-init-scripts

You can see the actual 6-0 script here:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-0-stable/lib/support/init.d/gitlab

and the 6-1 script here:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-1-stable/lib/support/init.d/gitlab

**Update3**

Tried starting script using bash -x

```
root@gitlab:/etc/init.d# bash -x /etc/init.d/gitlab start
+ RAILS_ENV=production
+ app_root=/home/git/gitlab
+ app_user=git
+ unicorn_conf=/home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb
+ pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids
+ socket_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets
+ web_server_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
+ sidekiq_pid_path=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
+ '[' root '!=' git ']'
+ sudo -u git -H -i /etc/init.d/gitlab start
+ exit
```

## Success,

It appears that the script must be run as the user 'git'.

Comment: Anything useful in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've added it to the question. Nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: Do you by chance still have the previous init script around, so as to run a `diff -ub` against the current one?

Comment: @dawud , Yes I do have both scripts and I ran a diff -ub. (see update2 in the question). It looks like there were a lot of changes.

Comment: Try running `gitlab start` (i.e. add the *start* parameter). Also, I notice that one of the changes was to move from `bash` to `sh` on line #1. As far as I can see the script ought to output *something* whatever happens. If it does *absolutely nothing*, might it be a shell problem? (try changing the `sh` to `bash` in line #1, just to be sure).

Comment: what makes you think that the problem is due to replacing an init.d script rather than just bugs in the new version of the script?  btw, stracing a shell script isn't usually very useful - try running it with `bash -x` instead.  e.g. `bash -x /etc/init.d/gitlab start`

Comment: if you use ubuntu, ubuntu uses Upstart and run some services under Upsatrt insead of `/etc/rcN.d` if you want to diable them, you should run `echo "manual" |tee -a /etc/init/yourservice.override`

Comment: @CraigSanders I've checked the irc channel and the gitlab issues page and no one else has reported issues with the script. I haven't worked a lot with ubuntu,(just centos) so I though it could be something simple I was missing.

Comment: Thanks @CraigSanders for the bash -x idea. I was able to start the script with sudo -u git -H /etc/init.d/gitlab start. I still need to figure out how to make the script only run as git.

Comment: would be interesting to see what happens in the script when run as user git.  try editing the script and adding `set -x` somewhere near the start of the script (this does same thing as running with `bash -x`), and then `sudo -u git -H -i /etc/init.d/gitlab start`.  my guess is that there's likely some permissions or ownership problem (e.g. files or dirs or sockets in ~gitlab owned by root rather than by user git)

Comment: @CraigSanders good idea, I tried your suggestion, but it did not show any extra information. Thanks to your comment about bash -x, I figured out that the script had an extra exit statement in it (not sure how that slipped past QA). I've fixed the issue and created a pull request https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5218 If you turn your comments into an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: as i suspected, a bug in the script rather than a problem with replacing an init.d script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug bash or shell scripts, it's useful to either run it with `bash -x` or edit the script and add a line saying `set -x`.  This will show the execution trace of each line in the script as it is executed, along with the value of variable assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to the problem which does not require changing the init script.

The instructions for gitlab instruct the user to use `adduser --disabled-login`. Instead of using `adduser` I used puppet to add the user and set the default shell to /bin/false instead of /bin/bash.

As soon as I changed my 'git' user's shell to /bin/bash, the init script started working correctly again.